# Searching CSV files with Pandas (unique id's) - Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking into searching a csv file with 242000 rows and want to sum the unique identifiers in one of the columns. The column name is 'logid' and has a number of different values i.e. 1002, 3004, 5003. I want to search the csv file using the panda dataframe and sum the amount of unique identifiers. If possible I would then like to create a new csv file that stores this information. For example if I find there are 50 logid's of 1004 I would then like to create a csv file that has column name 1004 and the count of 50 displayed below. I would do this for all unique identifiers and add them in the same csv file. I am completely new at this and have done some searching but no idea where to start.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions, and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn how to create minimal, complete, and verifiable examples.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't post your code I can give you an answer only about the general way it would work.

1. Load the CSV file into a pd.Dataframe using [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv)
2. Save all values which a occurence > 1 in a seperate df1 using [pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) like:

   df1=df.drop_duplicates(keep="first)

--> This Will return a DataFrame which only contains the rows with the first occurence of duplicate values. E.g. if the value 1000 is in 5 rows only the first row will be returned while the others are dropped.

--> Applying df1.shape[0] will return you the number of duplicate values in your df.

3.If you want to store all rows of df which contain a "duplicate value" in a seperate CSV file you have to do smth like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"A":[0,1,2,3,0,1,2,5,5]}) # This should represent your original data set
print(df)

df1=df.drop_duplicates(subset="A",keep="first") #I assume the column with the duplicate values is columns "A" if you want to check the whole row just omit the subset keyword.

print(df1)
list=[]


for m in df1["A"]:
    mask=(df==m)
    list.append(df[mask].dropna())

for dfx in range(len(list)):
    name="file{0}".format(dfx)
    list[dfx].to_csv(r"YOUR PATH\{0}".format(name))
```

Comment: Could I help you with this?