# Counting unique id's in csv file using Pandas (python)

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So I've currently got a dataset that has a column called 'logid' which consists of 4 digit numbers. I have about 200k rows in my csv files and I would like to count each unique logid and output it something like this;

Logid | #ofoccurences for each unique id. So it might be 1000 | 10 meaning that the logid 1000 is seen 10 times in the csv file column 'logid'. The separator | is not necessary, just making it easier for you guys to read. This is my code currently:

```
import pandas as pd
import os, sys
import glob
count = 0
path = "C:\\Users\\cam19\\Desktop\\New folder\\*.csv"
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    df = pd.read_csv(fname, dtype=None, names=['my_data'], low_memory=False)
    counts = df['my_data'].value_counts()
counts
```

Using this I get a weird output that I dont quite understand:

```
4            16463
10013          490
pserverno        1
Name: my_data, dtype: int64
```

I know I am doing something wrong in the last line

> counts = df['my_data'].value_counts()

but I am not too sure what. For reference the values I am extracting are from row C in the excel file (so I guess thats column 3?) Thanks in advance!

Comment: will you provide your `csv` file structure?

Comment: Its made up for 64 columns (all str values) and 200k rows made up of int values. I only want to look into the 3rd row which has the heading 'logid' but for all 200k rows. They are %100 all integers. Not sure what else you mean.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching CSV files with Pandas (unique id's) - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45316031/searching-csv-files-with-pandas-unique-ids-python)

Comment: Seems like you were asking the same question a few days ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45316031/searching-csv-files-with-pandas-unique-ids-python).   How is this different?  Why not simply edit the first question with your updated code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok. from my understanding. I think `csv` file may be like this.

```
row1,row1,row1
row2,row2,row2
row3,row3,row3
logid,header1,header2
1000,a,b
1001,c,d
1000,e,f
1001,g,h
```

And I have all done this with this format of `csv` file like

```
# skipping the first three row
df = pd.read_csv("file_name.csv", skiprows=3)
print(df['logid'].value_counts())
```

And the output look like this

```
1001    2
1000    2
```

Hope this will help.

**update 1**

```
 df = pd.read_csv(fname, dtype=None, names=['my_data'], low_memory=False)
```

in this line the parameter `names = ['my_data']` creates a new header of the data frame. As your `csv` file has header row so you can skip this parameter. And as the main header you want to `row3` so you can skip first three row. And last one thing you are reading all `csv` file in given path. So be conscious all of the `csv` files are same format. Happy codding.

Comment: The csv file was slightly different to how you described; however using this section of your given code; print(df['logid'].value_counts()), I was able to output the logid and the number of times it shows up in the column of the csv file. Thanks!!

Comment: @jezrael  - I did some modification of you code and post it two my answer. Ok let me remove it. :(

Answer (score 1):

I think you need create  one big `DataFrame` by `append` all `df` to `list` and then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) first:

```
dfs = []
path = "C:\\Users\\cam19\\Desktop\\New folder\\*.csv"
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    df = pd.read_csv(fname, dtype=None, usecols=['logid'], low_memory=False)
    dfs.append(df)

df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Then use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) - output is `Series`. So for `2 column DataFrame` need [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
counts = df['my_data'].value_counts().rename_axis('my_data').reset_index(name='count')
counts
```

Or [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
counts = df.groupby('my_data').size().reset_index(name='count')
counts
```

Comment: This would work; however, I have 6000 csv files with 200000 rows in each file, concating them would not be a wise idea. In addition, I also needed the data separate for each file. Look below for the answer I was looking for if you are curious :)

Comment: Do you think solution of `R.A.Munna`? What was helpful with it? I dont understand. Can you explain more?

Comment: Ok, and is possible filter column `logid` only by `df = pd.read_csv(fname, dtype=None, usecols=['logid'], low_memory=False)` ? I edit my answer.

Comment: I think remove all columns without `logid` - http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#filtering-columns-usecols

Answer (score 0):

you may try this.

```
counts = df['logid'].value_counts()
```

Now the "counts" should give you the count of each value.

Comment: I get this error, 'the label [logid] is not in the [index]'